# How to wrap a key with another object in entity framework / code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I just started prototyping our existing object model in entity framework/code first and hit my first snag.  Unfortunately the documentation for this seems to be very scarce.

My key is not a primitive but an object that wraps a primitive.  How do I get this to work with EF/Code first:

```
public class EFCategoryIdentity 
{
    public string IdentityValue { get; private set; }
    public EFCategoryIdentity(string value)
    {
        IdentityValue = value;
    }
}

public class EFCategory
{
    [Key]
    public EFCategoryIdentity CategoryIdentity { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<EFProduct> Products { get; set; }
}

public class EFProduct
{
    [Key]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual EFCategory Category { get; set; }
}
```

What do I need to put here to make this work?

```
public class MyTestContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<EFCategory> Categories { get; set; }
    public DbSet<EFProduct> Products { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<EFCategory>()
            .// Help!
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You can't configure such a primary key in EF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entity framework can use only primitive types as keys. Every time you wrap some mapped property to separate type you are creating complex type. Complex types have some limitation

- They cannot be keys
- They cannot contain keys
- They cannot contain navigation properties
- etc.